# Debugging Android apps via IntelliJ/Android SDK on my Samsung Galaxy S10+ results in "Error while Installing APKs"

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I decided to generate even more money and develop my first app for Android. When I want to deploy my app (just the skeleton code from IntelliJ/Android SDK) with one `MainActivity` I am getting the following error.

[image]

The log of the run looks like this.

> 5/07 21:32:35: Launching app
>
> $ adb install-multiple -r -t
>
> C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_7.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_6.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_8.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_9.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_4.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_5.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_3.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\resources\instant-run\debug\resources-debug.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_0.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_1.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\dep\dependencies.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\split-apk\debug\slices\slice_2.apk C:\Users\Tony\Code\Java\PureWallpaper\app\build\intermediates\instant-run-apk\debug\app-debug.apk
>
> $ adb shell pm uninstall com.stark.purewallpaper
>
> Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: com.stark.purewallpaper
>       at com.android.server.pm.Settings.getInstallerPackageNameLPr(Settings.java:4671)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getInstallerPackageName(PackageManagerService.java:25342)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:25348)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:21062)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:924)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:1486)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:193)
>       at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:103)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:25884)
>       at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:642)
>       at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:540)
>       at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3329)
>       at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:4763)
>       at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:739)
>       Error while Installing APKs

The event log looks like this.

> 21:32  Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>      21:32  Gradle build finished in 493 ms
>      21:32  Failed to finalize session : -118

Things I tried on the phone:

- re-enabled dev mode
- re-enabled USB debugging
- tried different default usb configurations like "picture" or "file" transfer
- tried activating "wait for debugger" option

Things I tried in IntelliJ:

- deactivated "Instant Run"
- installed all SDK tools, including the "Google USB Driver"
- cleaned and rebuild the project

IntelliJ can clearly see my device, it even detects the type correctly.

[image]

I am on:

- Windows 10
- IntelliJ 2019.1.1
- Newest Android SDK that comes with IntelliJ

I decided to try this on Android Studio 3.4 and I'm getting same error.

[image]

I am able to run the app inside the emulator/virtual device but not on my Samsung Galaxy S10+. Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Android Studio are you using / what platform? I had this issue on 3.3+ on MacOS, I installed an older version and it worked fine, I had already tried everything you listed with no luck.

Comment: @Mark No idea how to find the version number of Android studio in IntelliJ. I am on Windows 10.

Comment: Ah you're on IntelliJ, sorry thought it was Android Studio. Have you tried using the "Invalidate Caches/Restart" option in the IDE? I think it's under the File menu section

Comment: Good luck with generating "even more money"! :'-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally, after days, found out what it was. My company forced a security policy on my phone after I configured the e-mail app to receive work mail. After deactivating the policy in security settings I was able to deploy the app without any problems.

Answer (score 5):

If none of the solution mentioned above works, you can turn off the instant run option as shown in the [image] from setting

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

1. **Build** > *Clean Project*
2. **Build** > *Rebuild Project*
3. **Build** > *Make Project (Ctrl + F9)*
4. Try to use this **File** > *Invalidates cache/restart*

Lastly, try to **sync project with Gradle file** which can be found in the right corner top

Comment: I followed the steps several times, except for "sync project with Gradle file". I can't see that option in the IDE. Until now no success :/

Comment: I found the last step in Android Studio 3.4 but it did not help as well.

Comment: did you try to uninstall the app in the device?  then do it again the steps before installing again in the device :)

Comment: The app is never installed in the phone.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to your **Apps** menu from your Android device **Settings**.
2. Find your app, probably name is **PureWallpaper** according to your logs.
3. Uninstall it.
4. Then try to install it again.

**Explanation:**

According to your error logs, it looks like your device has the same app installed but with different signature signed with different keystore.

Comment: Nope. I already tried that. No app with that name is installed.

Comment: Multiple users enabled? @Tony Stark

Comment: @Toaster On the phone? No.

Answer (score 0):

This was happen to me many times ,

This is just a warning ,It try to say that the app you want to install on your device is already installed on your device ,but the problem is it is signed with different credentials .

For eg:-
their was a release apk of the same app installed on your device and you are trying to install debug apk on same device.

This error also try to say that the that all the data which are saved by that apk will be lost.

Side note:- after clicking OK,sometimes android studio gives me error that it is unable to install but actually it installed.